# При уменьшении окна появляется белая область снизу

Tags: html, css

Когда меняешь ширину браузера, фон по ширине подстраивается, а по высоте нет. И в итоге выходит, что появляется белая область снизу.

[image: обычное состояние]

[image: при уменьшении ширины браузера]

Весь HTML код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>nevazhno</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card-hover"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Весь CSS код:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Mono+One&display=swap');

body {
    background: url(assets/background.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; 
}

.card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 501px;
    height: 390px;
    left: calc(50% - 501px/2 - 0.5px);
    top: calc(50% - 390px/2 + 99.5px);
    background: linear-gradient(154.98deg, #0A0A0A 0%, #1E1E1E 100%);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

.card-hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 501px;
    height: 217px;
    left: calc(50% - 501px/2 - 0.5px);
    top: calc(50% - 217px/2 - 204px);
    background: #0D0D0D;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 215px;
    height: 215px;
    left: calc(50% - 215px/2 - 0.5px);
    top: calc(50% - 215px/2 - 205px);
    pointer-events: none;
}

a {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   margin: -27px 108px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
   transition: 0.3s;
   border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Что за квадраты Малевича?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте `background-size: cover`; Хотя судя по вашему скрину ваш фон лучше сделать через CSS стили

Comment: Но мне нужен именно этот фон, background-size: cover, background-size: contain и т.д. не помогают

Comment: Ты уверен что это фон тебе ломает ? Очень похоже на iframe....  Может там height зафиксирован ?

Comment: Без понятия, могу весь код скинуть, надо?

Comment: Можешь переделать, потому что так не понятно

Comment: Вроде переделал, вставил весь код, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Вам необходимо через медиавыражения  задавать необходимые фоны   @media (max-width:1490px)  body {background: url(assets/background-middle.jpg) } и тд.  Сейчас они просто пропорционально уменьшаются относительно экрана.

Comment: Я только учусь и не понимаю этого, я попытался сделать через @media, но фон или пропадает, или ошибка не исправляется. Можете показать как правильно это вставить, чтобы у меня всё нормально работало?

Comment: Для начала создай из текущего фона, новое изображение которое будет по высоте таким же, но по ширине 1490px (ну или тот размер где у тебя начинает появляться этот сдвиг), дальше положи это изображение возле текущего и вызываешь его как написано выше. Так же почитай про css свойство @media (max-width: ) Его обязательно надо понимать как и когда применять .

Comment: Видимо я слишком глупый для этого. https://i.imgur.com/Vk0txZj.png

Comment: Почитайте про @media, я сходу вижу что вы забыли поставить {} для медиа, и эти вызовы должны ити после основного кода CSS, нарушен порядок

Comment: Ну вот теперь вроде всё работает, но только при обычном масштабе в браузере, если менять масштаб то проблема снова появляется.
https://i.imgur.com/pGFRb4d.png
https://i.imgur.com/fKZAGFT.png

Comment: Вам необходимо подобрать нужные бэкграунд изображения под нужные точки перехода. Можно ещё попробовать поиграться с высотой body {height:100vh;background-size: cover; } Но обычно это решается разными бэкграундами под разные разрешения экранов. И да, ваш фон можно реализовать через CSS + 2 SVG разблюреных элемента  (или даже 1).

Comment: Ладно, думаю мне стоит немного подучиться. Навряд ли кто-то будет специально менять масштаб страницы и изменять ширину браузера, поэтому это не так критично. Ну в общем-то спасибо, я многому научился благодаря вам.